# Spaces in a CSV file are discarded by CSV Serde in Redshift spectrum tables

Tags: opencsv, amazon-redshift-spectrum

My CSV file looks like

```
"col1","col2","col3"
"1","ab","2 "
"2","xy","  "
```

I have created an external table on top of it with all fields as varchar and the properties as below:

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
STORED AS textfile
LOCATION 's3://bucketname/foldername'
TABLE PROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1','serialization.null.format'='')
```

However, this reads my file as below. i.e. without spaces in the 3rd column in 1st row and null in the 3rd column of the 2nd row.

```
1->ab->2
2->xy->null
```

Even if i remove the serilization property, i am not getting the desired two blank spaces in the 2nd row.

Is this a limitation in the sense that CSV Serde discards the blankspaces or is there a workaround to achieve this?

Thanks to Bill, I have tried few Regex to parse this:

```
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('input.regex'='\"(.*)\",\"(.*)\",\"(.*)\"')
or
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('input.regex'='"(.*)","(.*)","(.*)"')
```

With the above the fields are getting trimmed by 1 digit at the end.

So, I moved the double quote inside the brackets as below and even tried using the escape char

```
('input.regex'='(".*"),(".*"),(".*")')
or
('input.regex'='(\".*\"),(\".*\"),(\".*\")')

"1" "ab"    "2 "
"2" "xy"    "  "
```

Now everything is coming as it, the blank spaces, lagging spaces but now the double quotes are also coming as part of data.

Funny thing is, if i keep the escape char in only the first column, then that field is enclosed in " even in o/p but the other fields comes clean.

```
('input.regex'='(\".*\"),(".*"),(".*")')

"1" ab  2 
"2" xy  blankspace
```

Comment: What is the data type of your third column?  This is earlier in the create external table statement

Comment: It's varchar(10). Well since all the columns are enclosed in double quotes, I can't make it integer.

Comment: Thanks and not true - other data types can be quoted but cannot but the empty string.

Comment: Thanks -yes you are correct. Are u saying "" cannot be there for a non-varchar field or it can't be there at all?

Comment: The CSV serdes first reads everything as strings and then convert to the specified data type.  If the quote char is set (and it is " by default) these will be stripped at the initial read stage.  If "" is to end up as an INT if will converted to NULL as there is no other possibility.  But for a string data type it is ambiguous as to mean empty string or NULL.   The frc CSV spec handles this but the serdes does not have the syntax for this clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into the limitations of the apache serdes when it comes to full frc4180 CSV files.  (Yes there is a spec for CSV - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180)  There are several problems with these serdes - you cannot embed newlines (record separator) inside a fields (by default), you cannot have empty strings and NULL in the same file, etc.  This is a major issue for many when using Glue or Athena and a major gripe of mine.  This has created a schism between the apache community and the traditional data community which has used the full CSV spec for decades.

So to solving your issue.  You could use the regex serdes but this will require a different pattern for each file format - ick.  Given the example you have provided you can move to ROW FORMAT DELIMITED but I don't believe you can have a quote character and this bring other limitations but with the right data and some post-processing you may be able to make this work.

The ironclad solution is to accept that CSV serdes are flawed and don't provide full support for all the data you may have.  This means that you either keep your data to what these serdes can do or process your S3-sourced data tables to another format.  If you go this way I would recommend that your COPY the CSV files into Redshift (you are already paying for one of these) and UNLOAD the data back out as Parquet or ORC.  Redshift supports reading full specification CSV files (with COPY) and these other formats have better implemented serdes.

Per request - the regex serdes a syntax should look something like (untested):

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = "\"(.*)\",\"(.*)\",\"(.*)\"")
```

Comment: Yes, using the ROW FORMAT DELIMITED would consider the double quotes as part of data, that would need post processing as well as could trim some data value where the size defined is exactly same as data. I am already using redshift table to store the processed o/p from this file, so that isn't a option at this stage. Regarding the regex, would you be able to provide for this sample 3 column file, so that I could extend it to my actual file?

Comment: I'll update the answer with an approximate syntax for the regex serdes

Comment: Thanks for the syntax. 
With the one you gave, except that it need to be enclosed in single quotes instead of double quotes, the fields are getting trimmed by 1 digit at the end (even if i remove the escape character).
So, i moved the double quote inside the brackets ('input.regex'='(".*"),(".*"),(".*")') . Now everything is coming as it, except it also includes the double quotes (even with adding the escape char \). 
I am still working on it to find the correct exp. Adding it in answer for better readability.

Comment: That all sounds right.  I did it off the cuff from an example from a while back.  Great to hear you got it working.  One note - I don't think that serde is the fastest but hopefully it will meet your needs.